# Admob OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, android, exception, admob, out-of-memory

Can anyone help me regarding this error?

```
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.upstream.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12872002@12.8.72 (000304-202717283):10)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.extractor.g.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12872002@12.8.72 (000304-202717283):22)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.extractor.k.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12872002@12.8.72 (000304-202717283):38)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.extractor.mp4.f.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12872002@12.8.72 (000304-202717283):116)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.upstream.p.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12872002@12.8.72 (000304-202717283):39)

1. at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call
    (Executors.java:422)
2. at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
3. at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
4. at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
5. at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Without code it is almost impossible to help you.

Comment: Then first I should find out a way to track the code and find out where this error occurs.

Comment: Not your fault, report it to admob.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error is thrown when there is insufficient space to **allocate an object in the Java heap**.

In this case, The garbage collector cannot make space available to accommodate a new object, and the heap cannot be expanded further. Also, this error may be thrown when there is insufficient native memory to support the loading of a Java class (Intent in android language).

[Your concern is here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/mPWvc7o7xus/5alUwHv_AgAJ)
In a rare instance, **a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError may be thrown when an excessive amount of time is being spent doing garbage collection and little memory is being freed**.

To understand OutOfMemoryError [click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html).